# Error during Eloquent Model Creation - mutator executes but mutated Date field not present in insert statement - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, php-carbon

mySQL DATE format is `Y-m-d`
For localization reasons, users submit date fields to my Laravel 5.4 application in the `d-m-Y` form, which are saved to a `detenutodal` field in mySQL.

I used mutators to convert the two formats, in my `Attore` model, like this.

```
<?php
namespace App;

//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Attore extends Model
{

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
        'detenutodal'
    ];

    /**
     * detenutodal: DB Y-m-d => m-d-Y
     *
     * @param  date  $value
     * @return date
     */
    public function getDetenutodalAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y');
    }

    /**
     * detenutodal: m-d-Y => DB Y-m-d 
     *
     * @param  date  $value
     * @return date
     */
    public function setDetenutodalAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}
```

as you may see, the `detenutodal` attribute is added to the `$dates` to make it into a `Carbon` instance (not declaring it seems to make no difference. Actually I was unable to have `detenutodal` behave like a Carbon instance, and I had to explicitly call `Carbon::parse`)

I create a new `Attore` model in `AttoreController` like this:

```
$this->validate(request(), [
    'detenutodal' =>'nullable|date_format:"d-m-Y"',
    ]);

Attore::create(request()->all());
```

The detenutodal field is correctly validated,  and I am sure the mutator is called as I `dd`'ed its invocation. the correct `detenutodal` value is passed to it - e.g. `30-06-1943` and it returns `1943-06-30`.

but the `create` fails with this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'detenutodal' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `attores` (`nome`, `enteopersona`, `paternita`, `maternita`, `annonascita`, `luogonascita`, `residenza`, `professione`, `gradoistruzione`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Aminto Pestalozzi, persona, Agenore Pestalozzi, Giacinta Tortelazzi, 1910, Caorso in Strà' lva', Via Morigi 4, Caorso, Bracciante, Scuola professionale, 2017-05-18 14:23:22, 2017-05-18 14:23:22))
```

As you may see, mySQL complains that `detenutodal` has no default value as `detenutodal` has completely disappeared from the query, while I would expect that the mutator correctly updated the field before the invocation of `Attore::create` and added it to the query.

Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : Your mutator is wrong.

```
public function setDetenutodalAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['detenutodal'] = Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

You need to set the fillable property.

```
protected $fillable = ['detenutodal'];
```

or set the guarded to so

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

You allow nullable value for the date, is this field nullable?

Comment: this
     `$this->attributes['detenutodal']`

was the solution. was looking for the problem in all wrong place and not in a bad copypaste mistake .... thanks

Answer (score 0):

detenutodal field is null and has not default value in mysql engine please start from controller dump your detenutodal field first to check if it's has value or not then check if value is datetime value or not .

Comment: It has a value, it gets through the validation and gets mutated, but it does not get included in the query

to be clear, adding a couple debug lines like this:

    public function setDetenutodalAttribute($value)
    {
        echo $value;
        echo '<br />';
        dd(Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d'));

with an input from form of 30-06-1943

I get this output

30-06-1943
"1943-06-30"

So the validator passes, and the mutator is called. but then the value is not considered for insertion

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explicitly allow `detenutodal` field to be "filled".

Laravel has a security mechanism by default against [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment)

This should fix it.

```
protected $fillable = ['detenutodal'];
```

Comment: I had declared the $guarded attributes in Attore's superclass. 

`class Model extends Eloquent
{
    //
    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
       ];
}`

Without the mutators, insertion works